# ajax post - I want to change the Accept-Encoding header value

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, header

I am using jQuery ajax to call my WCF service with an HTTP POST. The response is GZIP encoded, and this causes problems in my environment. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384176/wcf-service-returns-incorrect-content-length-when-using-gzip-encoding)). If the response is not GZIP encoded everything is fine.

So looking in Fiddler, I see that the jQuery generated query has the following headers:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
```

If, via fiddler, i change this value to `None`, then the response is not compressed, which is what I want. All that I need to do is change the value in the "Accept-Encoding" header.

It seems that it is not possible to change this header value via the `.ajax` command. (See [this forum post](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-beforesend-accept-encoding-behavior)).

Can anyone tell me what options I have to change this header value.

Here's my current attempt. My `headers` parameter seems to be ignored.

```
    $telerik.$.ajaxSetup({
        accepts: 'application/json, text/javascript, */*'
    });

    var parameters = {
        "playerId": args.playerId
    };

    var dataInJsonFormat = '{ "playerId": ' + args.playerId + '}';

    var ajaxCallParameters = {
        accepts: 'application/json, text/javascript, */*',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "../Services/CmsWebService.svc/SendUpdateRequestToPlayer",
        headers: { "Accept-Encoding" : "None" },
        type: "POST",
        data: dataInJsonFormat,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var errorString = 'Error thrown from ajax call: ' + textStatus + 'Error: ' + errorThrown;
            var displayPanel = document.getElementById('requestStatusUpdateResults');
            $telerik.$(displayPanel).text(errorString);

        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var displayPanel = document.getElementById('requestStatusUpdateResults');
            $telerik.$(displayPanel).text(data.d);
        }
    };

    $telerik.$.ajax(ajaxCallParameters);
```

Comment: Does this answer help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771878/jquery-ajax-request-change-user-agent

Answer (score 5):

This value is probably being overwritten later in the process.

> Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
>   headers (default: {}) description
>   Type: PlainObject
>   An object of additional header key/value pairs to send along with the request. **This setting is set before the beforeSend function is called; therefore, any values in the headers setting can be overwritten from within the beforeSend function**.

Try implementing `beforeSend` as seen in the demo code below and the header value(s) should get to the final request now (fingers crossed).

```
var ajaxParams = {
    accepts: 'text/html',
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'text/html',
    url: 'http://www.google.com',
    type: 'GET',
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
        // set request headers here rather than in the ajax 'headers' object
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'deflate');
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log('Yay!');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Oh no!');
    },
    complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(jqXHR.status);
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
    }
};

$.ajax(ajaxParams);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible because of choosing the right encoding type by browser. 
If you do this

```
var ajaxParams = {
accepts: 'text/html',
async: true,
cache: false,
contentType: 'text/html',
url: 'http://www.google.com',
type: 'GET',
beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
    // set request headers here rather than in the ajax 'headers' object
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'deflate');
},......
```

You'll see this error:

```
Refused to set unsafe header "Accept-Encoding"
```

Ref: [App Engine Accept-Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772061/app-engine-accept-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that 'none' is a valid option there. I believe if you set the headers to accept encoding 'deflate' rather than 'none', that should sort out your problem.

e.g.

```
headers: { 'Accept-Encoding' : 'deflate' }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that isn't actually the problem. The problem is that I can't change the 'Accept-Encoding' value to anything, neither 'none' nor 'deflate'.

Comment: Ah, I see. My longer answer should help then.