# How can setting a Response.Filter cause a long (2 minutes) delay before returning?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, response.filter

I have a .svc WCF web service that looks like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
public XElement GetFunStuff(Stream raw) {

    // make an XElement document ...

    // Compress it.
    // !!!! If I do this, it takes 2 minutes.  If I do NOT, it takes under a second.
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter = new DeflateStream(context.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
    }

    return xml;
}
```

Given my current test data, the uncompresed XML response is 70k.  Compressed, it is 6k.  Both ways functionally work, in that they return the response (except one is marked deflate).  My test server is not being used by anything else, and during the test, there's no obvious spike in CPU usage.

So how is it that the compressed response takes somewhere between ~122 and ~128 seconds to respond, but the uncompressed response takes (a more expected) second or two?  What can it possibly be hanging up on or timing out on?

[EDIT] I just noticed that my Content-Length is being set (by what, I am not sure) to the uncompressed size, rather than the compressed size.  That then keeps the server waiting until something forcibly closes the connection or gives up.  So the question becomes, why is my Content-Length wrong?   ... This might be related... [WCF service returns incorrect Content-Length when using gzip encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384176/wcf-service-returns-incorrect-content-length-when-using-gzip-encoding)