# WCF jquery parsererror unterminated string constant response

Tags: wcf

For my recent project, I created a Web service that returns an array of custom type to jquery client-side code. WCF is called by `$.ajax` command and is in the same domain.

When I run my web applicaiton on localhost (which is IIS run on local machine), everything works fine. When I deploy it to our integration server, suddenly ajax call to WCF ends with an error: "parsererror - unterminated string constant" and status of 200. Returned message is however something like `"[{\"Text\":\"Test dodatnih naslov"`, which of course is not a correct json format.

Correct response should have been: `"[{"Text":"Test dodatnih naslovov","Value":"100"},{"Text":"Test dodatnih naslovov - ISO2","Value":"101"},{"Text":"UPDATE","Value":"102"}]"`

I have traced WCf service for malfuncitons, but it does not seem to be crashing. I also tried and set timeout to ajax call, but to no avail. Some help would be much appreciated.

My IIS is IIS7, where integration runs IIS6 on Windows Server 2008.

js file

```
function InsuranceClientContact_ItemsRequesting(o, e) {
    var $ = $telerik.$;
    var urlSvc = ServiceBaseUrl + '/GetContacts'
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlSvc,
        data: '{"ixClient": ' + selectedItemId + '}', //selectedItemId is a positive number
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            // do something
        },
        error: function (result) {
            var msg = result.status + " - " + result.statusText;
            setTimeout(function () { throw new Error(msg) }, 0);
        }
    });
```

wcf interface

```
namespace Sid.Skode.Web.Services.Populate {
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IInsuranceClientContactService {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method="POST",
            BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
            ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        Contact[] GetContacts(long ixClient);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Contact {
        [DataMember]
        public string Text;
        [DataMember]
        public string Value;
    }

}
```

wcf service implementation

```
namespace Sid.Skode.Web.Services.Populate {
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements( RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed )]
    public class InsuranceClientContactService : IInsuranceClientContactService {

        public Contact[] GetContacts( long ixClient ) {
            return GetContactsFromDatabase( ixClient );
        }

        #region Private methods

        private Contact[] GetContactsFromDatabase( long ixClient ) {
            DataTable dt = GetDataFromDataBaseById( ixClient );
            return ConvertDataTableToContactArray( dt );
        }        

        private DataTable GetDataFromDataBaseById( long ixClient ) {
            AutoCompleteBLL model = new AutoCompleteBLL();
            return model.SearchContactsByPartner( ixClient );
        }

        private Contact[] ConvertDataTableToContactArray( DataTable dt ) {
            Contact[] rgContact = new Contact[dt.Rows.Count];
            int cnContact = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
                if (!dr.IsNull( "NAZIV" )) {
                    Contact contact = new Contact();
                    contact.Text = dr["NAZIV"].ToString();
                    contact.Value = dr["ID_DODATEN_KONTAKT"].ToString();
                    rgContact[cnContact++] = contact;
                }
            }
            return rgContact;
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

web.config wcf part

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="httpServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="httpEndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithTransportWindowsSecurity">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="Sid.Skode.Web.Services.Populate.InsuranceClientContactService" behaviorConfiguration="httpServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithTransportWindowsSecurity"
                  contract="Sid.Skode.Web.Services.Populate.IInsuranceClientContactService"
                  behaviorConfiguration="httpEndpointBehavior">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint
          address="mex"
          binding="mexHttpsBinding"
          bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384176/wcf-service-returns-incorrect-content-length-when-using-gzip-encoding), you need remove all instances of RadCompression http module from web config. Then, it works.